# Is Safari identical to other browsers built on the same Webkit version?

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, webkit

Is Safari as an application identical to that of any other application that is built on the same Webkit version?

I'm not talking about the UI elements, but API's, features, or resources that are solely available on Safari and accessible via Javascript? (Mainly for Safari version < 10)

Maybe specific or proprietary codecs, fonts, plugins?

Comment: Browsers must follow standards. Some browsers might implement other functionalities. For example, take the crypto API on Firefox or FS functions on Internet Explorer (and other things available through ActiveXObjects). They might not work on other browsers, or on their newer versions...

Comment: Thats what I'm looking for. Additional properties, API's that only Safari implements for various use cases. Something aside from the core webkit functionalities.

Comment: Any further ideas on this?